# Pass data from one view controller to the other using unwind segue with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Here is my code:
I am making the user to be able to select image from phone and then want to jump back to the previous view controller passing this image file too..

```
@IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if (segue.identifier == "unwindToThis") {




    }

}
```

Comment: You can use "segue.destinationViewController" to access the View Controller that you will be going to.  Then you can just make the image file equal to a property in that view controller.

Comment: that i can do.. do you have solution for this? i ll be very thankful to u

Comment: the thing is when i am doing yours solution navigation bar disappears..so i don't want to do that

Comment: You probably need to make your unwind segue go back to the navigation controller, rather than the view controller itself.

Comment: Nope.. it is going back to the first view controller.. but i want to pass the data to the second view controller.. and the unwind segue in in third view controller :/

Comment: Alternatively, create class kind of persistent storage, using singleton pattern, make your `UIImage` a property in this class so it's accessible from all view controllers within the app. Assign it from one controller unwind seque and check it in another view controller in viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Are you just using View Controllers, or is there a Navigation Bar Controller in there?

Comment: see, i have navigation controller 1st then login view controller for logging in then signup view controller.. there when we click the image view to select a profile pic it goes to other view controller then i want to select an image and give this image to signup viewcontroller's image view.. the whole problem! i m sorry for bothering you..

Comment: so if i use prepare for segue method.. navigation bar disappears in signupViewController by passing the profile pic.. that's why i m using unwind segue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your original view controller is still loaded in memory you can use an NSNotification via NSNotificationCenter.

In the view controller that needs the data, in viewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "imageReceived:", name: "imageReceived", object: self.videoDeviceInput?.device)
```

Then add the deinit method to the same controller, this will remove the observer when the view controller is no longer loaded.

```
deinit {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "imageReceived", object: nil)
}
```

Still in the same class create a method to handle the notification:

```
func imageReceived(notification: NSNotification) {
if let image = notification.object as? UIImage {

// Do your image stuff here.

}
}
```

In the view controller where you create or get the data you need to pass back you can to trigger the notification with the data like so:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("imageReceived", object: yourUIImage)
```

Comment: i have one more option.. i am using     navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) and now how can i pass data.. because prepareForSegue method is not working here..

Comment: If you use the solution I provided you can notify in viewWillDisappear.